# Finding the squares in a plane given n points

Tags: c, algorithm

Given n points in a plane , how many squares can be formed ...??

I tried this by calculating the distances between each 2 points , then sort them , and look for the squares in the points with four or more equal distances after verifying the points and slopes.

But this looks like an approach with very high complexity . Any other ideas ...??

I thought dynamic programming for checking for line segments of equal distances might work ... but could not get the idea quite right ....

Any better ideas???

P.S : The squares can be in any manner . They can overlap , have a common side, one square inside another ...

If possible please give a sample code to perform the above...

Comment: Are the coordinates integers or floating points?

Comment: Squares are made up of line segments not points, so this question makes litte sense -- what do you mean?  How unique many squares have some/all of their vertexes in the set of points?  How many squares contain a different set of points?  How many squares can cover the points?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let `d[i][j] = distances between points i and j`. We are interested in a function `count(i, j)` that returns, as fast as possible, the number of squares that we can draw by using points `i` and `j`.

Basically, `count(i, j)` will have to find two points `x` and `y` such that `d[i][j] = d[x][y]` and check if these 4 points really define a square.

You can use a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) to solve the problem in `O(n^2)` on average. Let `H[x] = list of all points (p, q) that have d[p][q] = x`.

Now, for each pair of points `(i, j)`, `count(i, j)` will have to iterate `H[ d[i][j] ]` and count the points in that list that form a square with points `i` and `j`.

This should run very fast in practice, and I don't think it can ever get worse than `O(n^3)` (I'm not even sure it can ever get that bad).

Comment: Note that the condition `d[i][j] = d[x][y] and d[i][x] = d[j][y] or d[i][y] = d[j][x]` doesn't guarantee that it's a square. You should still check that it is.

Answer (score 6):

This problem can be solved in `O(n^1.5)` time with `O(n)` space.

The basic idea is to group the points by X or Y coordinate, being careful to avoid making groups that are too large. The details are in the paper [Finding squares and rectangles in sets of points](http://www.cs.uu.nl/research/techreps/repo/CS-1989/1989-10.pdf). The paper also covers lots of other cases (allowing rotated squares, allowing rectangles, and working in higher dimensions).

I've paraphrased their 2d axis-aligned square finding algorithm below. Note that I changed their tree set to a hash set, which is why the time bound I gave is not `O(n^1.5 log(n))`:

1. Make a hash set of all the points. Something you can use to quickly check if a point is present.
2. Group the points by their X coordinate. Break any groups with more than `sqrt(n)` points apart, and re-group those now-free points by their Y coordinate. This guarantees the groups have at most `sqrt(n)` points *and* guarantees that for each square there's a group that has two of the square's corner points.
3. For every group `g`, for every pair of points `p,q` in `g`, check whether the other two points of the two possible squares containing `p` and `q` are present. Keep track of how many you find. Watch out for duplicates (are the two opposite points also in a group?).

Why does it work? Well, the only tricky thing is the regrouping. If either the left or right columns of a square are in groups that are not too large, the square will get found when that column group gets iterated. Otherwise *both* its top-left and top-right corners get regrouped, placed into the same row group, and the square will be found when that row group gets iterated.

Comment: Your step two sounds a bit confusing. I'd word it like this: Group some points by their X coordinate, and some by their Y coordinate, such that no group contains more than sqrt(n) points.

Comment: @YechielLabunsliy I agree that the current wording is a bit awkward, but yours omits how to actually achieve the grouping. Also it misses one of the conditions the groups must satisfy: for every square there must be one of its sides with both corner points in the same group.

Comment: Your edit sounds much better than before. Maybe less people will get to read the original paper now that your description is better

Comment: The 1989 technical report by van Kreveld and de Berg (linked above) was later published as a book chapter of [Graphs And Computational Geometry](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-52292-1_25), pp. 341-355, by Springer-Verlag (2005).  The title is the same, but some references (all pre-1989) are included in the published version (they seem to be missing in the PDF linked above).  Note that the authors consider only a decision problem, Does a square (or rectangle) exist with vertices in the point set?

Comment: I don't understand your third step. How do you find the other two points if 2 given points are known? Sorry if it's a noob question!

Answer (score 6):

I have a O(N^2) time, O(N) space solution:

Assume given points is an array of object Point, each Point has x,y.

1. First iterate through the array and add each item into an HashSet: This action de-duplicate and give us an O(1) access time. The whole process takes O(N) time
2. Using Math, Say vertices A, B, C, D can form a square, AC is known and it's a diagonal line, then the corresponding B, D is unique.  We could write a function to calculate that. This process is O(1) time
3. Now Let's get back to our thing. write a for-i-loop and a for-j-inner-loop. Say input[i] and input[j] form a diagonal line, find its anti-diagonal line in the set or not: If exist, counter ++; This process take O(N^2) time.

My code in C#:

```
    public int SquareCount(Point[] input)
    {
        int count = 0;

        HashSet<Point> set = new HashSet<Point>();
        foreach (var point in input)
            set.Add(point);

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < input.Length; j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                    continue;
                //For each Point i, Point j, check if b&d exist in set.
                Point[] DiagVertex = GetRestPints(input[i], input[j]);
                if (set.Contains(DiagVertex[0]) && set.Contains(DiagVertex[1]))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;

    }

    public Point[] GetRestPints(Point a, Point c)
    {
        Point[] res = new Point[2];

        int midX = (a.x + c.y) / 2;
        int midY = (a.y + c.y) / 2;

        int Ax = a.x - midX;
        int Ay = a.y - midY;
        int bX = midX - Ay;
        int bY = midY + Ax;
        Point b = new Point(bX,bY);

        int cX =  (c.x - midX);
        int cY =  (c.y - midY);
        int dX = midX - cY;
        int dY = midY + cX;
        Point d = new Point(dX,dY);

        res[0] = b;
        res[1] = d;
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: How are you calculating points B and D? Also, midX is `(a.x+c.x)/2`

Comment: https://qr.ae/pGI3tR - Guess this explains the above algo for `GetRestPints()`.

Comment: Won't we double count?

Comment: `j`  should start at `i + 1`. `(for int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like O(n^3) to me. A simple algo might be something like:

```
for each pair of points
    for each of 3 possible squares which might be formed from these two points
        test remaining points to see if they coincide with the other two vertices
```

Comment: How do you do the test in `O(n)`? Looks `O(n^4)` to me, unless you have a clever way to prevent the test from being done in `O(n^2)`.

Comment: IVlad: you only need to test each of n-2 points to see if they coincide with either of the two remaining vertices. Hence the test is O(n).

Comment: @Paul - then I'm guessing you're assuming you have the distances between each pair of points precomputed, is that correct? You should mention that, it might not be immediately obvious to everyone.

Comment: Here's an optimization: The points can be sorted by their coordinates in linear time by Radix Sort. The test then becomes a lookup of time O(log(n)). Thus, total time is O(n^2 * log(n)).

Comment: Also, when picking pairs, you can halve the runtime by avoiding comparing the same pair twice. It's still the same complexity, but twice faster nevertheless.

Comment: @IVlad - if you have 2 points, then calculating the possible locations of the other 2 points can be done mathematically. No need to precompute the distances between every pair of points.

Comment: @IVlad: no, I think you're missing the point. Two points define three possible squares, the coordinates of which can be calculated exactly - we're just looking for points which match the vertices, not looking at distances etc.

Comment: The other answer suggested using hashtables. I guess that's doable too. Add all points to a hashtable and perform your test through that. You'll get pretty close to O(n^2). You could get to a perfect O(n^2) by using a radix tree, but that's a bit more complex to implement.

Comment: @Vilx: I guess it depends on whether you're looking for an exact match on the coordinates (i.e.. integer coordinates only) or whether it's a continuous 2D space and you have some kind of matching tolerance (i.e. floating point coordinates).

Comment: @Paul R - well, the author hasn't specified. :) However I think you could make a data structure that would allow looking up nearby values as well. An index could do it, maybe a radix tree too.

Comment: Why from a segment there are 3 possible squares? I see the easy 2 given by the perpendicular to the segment

Comment: @Mattiatore: given two points you can make 2 different squares where the two points define one side of the square, and there’s a third square which can be formed if the two points define the diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime: O(nlog(n)^2), Space: θ(n), where n is the number of points.

For each point p
Add it to the existing arrays sorted in the x and y-axis respectively.
  For every pair of points that collide with p in the x and y-axis respectively
   If there exists another point on the opposite side of p, increment square count by one.
```

The intuition is counting how many squares a new point creates. All squares are created on the creation of its fourth point. A new point creates a new square if it has any colliding points on concerned axes and there exists the "fourth" point on the opposite side that completes the square. This exhausts all the possible distinct squares.

The insertion into the arrays can be done binary, and checking for the opposite point can be done by accessing a hashtable hashing the points' coordinates.

This algorithm is optimal for sparse points since there will be very little collision points to check. It is pessimal for dense-squares points for the opposite of the reason for that of optimal.

This algorithm can be further optimized by tracking if points in the axis array have a collision in the complementary axis.

Comment: How do you check for "collide"?
We also need to keep in mind that the square can very well be rotated along the axis!

Answer (score 1):

First, observe that each square can be uniquely identified with its center and the vector corresponding to one of the diagonals. And moreover, the other diagonal can be easily found out by finding the orthogonal vector of the same length, to the first one, which will be (-b, a) for a vector (a, b). Now, for each pair of points we will encode the unique square that can be formed by treating them as a diagonal, by the pair of coordinates of their mid-point, and the direction of the vector.

Initialize a multiset which stores two pairs of ints, lets call it *M*. Also initalize the integer variable *count* with value 0.

Now iterate over all the pairs of points (by a twice-nested loop on the list of points) :

1. Let the current pair of points be *p1: (x1, y1)* and *p2: (x2, y2)*. Then swap *(p1, p2)* if *x1 < x2*.
2. Insert the following pair of int-pairs into multiset *M* - *((x1+x2, y1+y2), (x1-x2, y1-y2))*. The first pair represents the midpoint (actually 2*midpoint coordinates), and the second pair represents the vector corresponding to the diagonal.
3. If *y1 > y2*, swap *(p1, p2)*. Query the count of the following in *M*: *((x1+x2, y1+y2), (abs(y1-y2), x1-x2))*. Increase the variable *count* by this answer to this query.

Finally return *count* ans the answer.

Time Complexity: Using multiset the T.C. is $O(n^2 \log n)$. But can be taken to $O(n^2)$ with hashmaps too.

Note: The swapping above have been performed in order to save the vector of diagonal with a particular orientation, here the orientation has been taken to be such that the x-coordinate of the vector is always positive.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: if a vertex A is one corner of a square, then there must be vertices B, C, D at the other corners with AB = AD and AC = sqrt(2)AB and AC must bisect BD.  Assuming every vertex has unique coordinates, I think you can solve this in O(n^2) with a hash table keying on (distance, angle).

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example implementation in Java - any comments welcome.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class SweepingLine {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point[] points = {
            new Point(1,1),
            new Point(1,4),
            new Point(4,1),
            new Point(4,4),
            new Point(7,1),
            new Point(7,4)
        };
        int max = Arrays.stream(points).mapToInt(p -> p.x).max().orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
        int count = countSquares(points, max);
        System.out.println(String.format("Found %d squares in %d x %d plane", count, max, max));
    }

    private static int countSquares(Point[] points, int max) {
        int count = 0;
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int x=0; x<max; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y<max; y++) {
                for(Point p: points) {
                    if (p.x == x && p.y == y) {
                        List<Integer> ys = map.computeIfAbsent(x, _u -> new ArrayList<Integer>());
                        ys.add(y);
                        Integer ley = null;
                        for (Integer ey: ys) {
                            if (ley != null) {
                                int d = ey - ley;
                                for (Point p2: points) {
                                    if (x + d == p2.x && p2.y == ey){
                                        count++;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ley = ey;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    private static class Point {
        public final int x;
        public final int y;
        public Point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete implemention of finding the diagonal points in C++!

- Given points a and c, return b and d, which lie on the opposite diagonal
- If b or d are not integer points, dicard them (optional)
- To find all squares generated by n points, can check out this [C++ implementation](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-square/discuss/103433/A-general-solution-to-find-combination-of-squares-in-n-points-in-O(n2)-time/286133/)
- Idea credited to Kevman. Hope it can help!

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> createDiag(vector<int>& a, vector<int>& c){
    double midX = (a[0] + c[0])/2.0;
    double midY = (a[1] + c[1])/2.0;
    
    double bx = midX - (a[1] - midY);
    double by = midY + (a[0] - midX);
    double dx = midX - (c[1] - midY);
    double dy = midY + (c[0] - midX);
    
    // discard the non-integer points
    double intpart;
    if(modf(bx, &intpart) != 0 or modf(by, &intpart) != 0 or modf(dx, &intpart) != 0 or modf(dy, &intpart) != 0){
        return {{}};
    }
    return {{(int)bx, (int)by}, {(int)dx, (int)dy}};
}
```