# Iterate multi-dimensional array and search for points that form squares

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computational-geometry

Part of my application is dedicated to recognizing the corners of all the object inside an image. I've found many ways to detect the corners, such as Harris corner detection and `GoodFeatureToTrack`. After some tests, `GoodFeatureToTrack` has proved to be the best solution but I'm stuck with the manipulation of the multi-dimensional array.

How can I iterate this type of array to check if inside the list of points there are four coordinates that form a square?

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(image, 150, 0.01, 15)
corners = np.int0(corners) 
print("Points")
for corner in corners:
   x, y = corner.ravel()
   cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
print(corners)
```

This is the actual result

**Points**

```
[[[141 265]]

[[148 176]]

[[136 360]]

[[233 358]]

[[192 218]]

[[130 465]]]
```

Comment: Do you want to test 4 points to be a square? or you want a rectangle that contains all points? or something else?

Comment: Related: [Detect square in a List of Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41199862/detect-square-in-a-list-of-points), [Finding the squares in a plane given n points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831144/finding-the-squares-in-a-plane-given-n-points), [2D Shape recognition and resolving algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811192/2d-shape-recognition-and-resolving-algorithm), [PyImageSearch - OpenCV shape detection](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/), ...

Comment: ... [GitHub - Simple "Square Detector" program.](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/squares.py)

Comment: @api55 I want to check if inside the output list there are 4 points that form a square. The list of points is much longer compared to the list that I have posted so I would like to have an example code to test inside my program to check if inside this list(points are randomly printed) there is a square.

Comment: Should rotated squares also be found?

Comment: @markuscosinus If possible yes

Comment: Which multi-dimensional array ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a function, that looks for square forming points in a list of points and returns the four points if they exist, `None` if not. For any two points in the list it first calculates their difference and turns this vector 90 degrees. Then it checks if either point1 + this vector **and** point2 + this vector **or** point1 - this vector **and** point2 - this vector are in the list and returns them if this is the case. `diffRotated.any()` is there just to make sure point1 and point2 are not the same.

```
def findSquare(points):
    for i, point1 in enumerate(points):
        for point2 in points[i+1:]:
            diffRotated = np.array([point2[1]-point1[1], point1[0]-point2[0]])
            if (diffRotated.any() and np.any(points == point1 + diffRotated) and np.any(points == point2 + diffRotated)):
                return np.array([point1, point2, point1 + diffRotated, point2 + diffRotated])
            elif(diffRotated.any() and np.any(points == point1 - diffRotated) and np.any(points == point2 - diffRotated)):
                return np.array([point1, point2, point1 - diffRotated, point2 - diffRotated])
    return None
```

For testing I added two entries to your list such that they form a square with two other points from your list:

```
points = np.array([[141, 265],
                   [148, 176],
                   [136, 360],
                   [233, 358],
                   [192, 218],
                   [130, 465],
                   [145, 167],
                   [ 94, 214]])
print(findSquare(points))
# array([[141, 265],
#        [192, 218],
#        [ 94, 214],
#        [145, 167]])
print(findSquare(points[:-1]))
# None
```

If you want to get **all** the squares you will need to modify my code and check that each square is only returned once. Also this code is not very efficient, there could be a way I haven't thought of to do this in a numpy stylish way.

Comment: Your code help me a lot! What I have to modify to retrieve all the square inside the list? @markuscosinus

Answer (score 0):

Consider all pairs of points in turn (`N(N-1)/2` of them), and consider them as the diagonal of a square. Then you can predict the positions of the two other vertices. There are two options:

- use a point-location structure such as a kD-tree and perform a fixed-radius near-neighbor search (assuming that you allow a small tolerance around the expected location);
- perform a local search in the image, spiraling from the expected location.

The first method will cost about O(N² Log N) operations, and the second O(N² t²), where t is the allowed tolerance in pixels.